# How to subscribe docker EE license for commercial setup?

Tags: docker

We are picking CentOS in our business, as AWS EC2 instance:

```
$ rpm --query centos-release
centos-release-7-6.1810.2.el7.centos.x86_64
```

Here are the steps to install docker EE on CentOS: https://docs.docker.com/install/linux/docker-ee/centos/

We want to launch jenkins on docker containers

---

We need docker engine to host docker containers in our business:

1) Are we suppose to buy docker EE? Is it a rule violation to use docker CE for commercial reasons?

2) How to subscribe a license for docker EE installation? to install on CentOS.

3) Does subscription allow docker EE installations on multiple EC2 instances?

Comment: Do you need functionality not provided in the open source part of Docker? If so you have to buy a license. Is the open source part of docker sufficient? If so you can use this commercially.

Comment: @vidarlo we want to launch jenkins setup on docker containers

Comment: What you're hosting is less interesting. The interesting thing is if you need functionality offered in EE. It's perfectly permissible to use apache2 licensed stuff commercially.

Comment: @vidarlo Are you referring to this capability matrix? https://docs.docker.com/install/overview/

Answer (score 0):

1. Are you supposed to? That's for you to decide. It's a rule to use what you need, taking into account the budget you have.
2. See here : https://docs.docker.com/ee/licensing/
3. See here : https://docs.docker.com/cluster/aws/